# flutter background service doesn't work in release mode

Tags: flutter

As I wrote in title, my background service doesn't work in release mode, still it works in debug mode.

this is my code. this is very simple foreground task code, added in flutter counter example code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service_android/flutter_background_service_android.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeService();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

const notificationChannelId = 'background_test';
const notificationId = 424;

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      notificationChannelId, 'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
    description:
      'hello world',
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
    ),
  );
  service.startService();
}

onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });
    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }
  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) async {
    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
        title: "App in background...",
        content: "Update ${DateTime.now()}",
      );
    }
    service.invoke(
      'update',
      {
        "current_date": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      },
    );
  });
}
//Some code for background task

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

when I execute this code in debug mode, foreground task runs well like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKoKj.jpg)

but when i run this with release mode, this doesn't work well like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcSEB.jpg)

what's wrong with this?

I've added permission in AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>`

but it didn't help with this problem.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am having the same problem. Flutter Background service works in debug mode, but not in release mode...

Answer (score 1):

There are certain optimizations that happen in release mode, which might cause some issues with background tasks and plugins.

To fix this issue, you can try adding a specific rule to the `ProGuard configuration` (for Android) to keep the necessary classes and methods used by the Flutter background service plugin.

You can take a look at [here](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

use `pragma` anotation for your background function

```
// pragma is Mandatory if the App is obfuscated or using Flutter 3.1+
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void yourBackgroundMethodc() {}
```

more about pragma https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/pragma-class.html

Comment: it doesn't work... is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. You need to put `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` for the background callback function for both Android and iOS.

So your onStart function looks like:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
    ...
}
```

and your onIosBackground function looks like:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
    ...
}
```

Also, if your background service code is not in your main.dart file and you are calling the initializeService() function which is in another dart file from the main.dart file, you should import the file into your main.dart file using path and not package. Example is:

Do not use

```
import 'package:project_name/path/to/dartfile.dart';
```

Instead, use

```
import 'path/to/dartfile.dart';
```

Hope it helps!